# Manga where a kid becomes super strong thinking he has wind magic when he really doesn't

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

Sorry for my English. A wizard takes in a kid with no mana. He ends up becoming super strong thinking he has wind magic when he really doesn't. He saves the kingdom within the first 13 chapters from a demon from another world. I'm not even sure if it was a iseaki or not. Best I can remember.

Answer (score 3):

The manga you are looking for is - "Doryoku Shisugita Sekai Saikyou no Butouka wa, Mahou Sekai wo Yoyuu de Ikinuku.". The link to the anilist page : [Doryoku Shisugita Sekai Saikyou no Butouka wa, Mahou Sekai wo Yoyuu de Ikinuku.](https://anilist.co/manga/109898/Doryoku-Shisugita-Sekai-Saikyou-no-Butouka-wa-Mahou-Sekai-wo-Yoyuu-de-Ikinuku/)

He believes he has 'wind' magic when it's just physics

From the description:

> A young martial artist who died was reincarnated into another world where magic was commonly used in a daily basis, as a boy named Ash. However, after knowing he would never be able to use magic, his parents abandoned him in the forest when he was still five years old.
>  
> Nevertheless, Ash who has a strong yearning for magic since his previous life, continued to train desperately every day under the guidance of a retired hero who picked him up.
> Unfortunately, even after he reached the age of 16, there was still no sign he would be able to use magic. However, Ash wasn’t aware that at that time, he already had enough power to defeat the demon lord with a single punch….